# swiper настройка пагинации

Tags: javascript, swiper

Как задать горизонтальному слайдеру вертикальную пагинацию в Swiper

```
var headerSlider = new Swiper(".header-slider__slider", {
  loop: true,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".header-slider__next",
    prevEl: ".header-slider__back",
  },
  thumbs: {
    swiper: headerSliderPrev,
  },
  pagination: {
    el: ".header-slider__pag",
    type: "progressbar",
  },
});
```